# jquery modal return value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, search

I
 have a jquery on my aspx page which loads a seperate aspx page through iframe inside a jquery modal.
I am passing the the value of a textbox to the jquery-modal.
Now I have a gridview in modal popup and evrytime i select a row I want to return those values back to base(parent page and populate some textboxes with gridview row in modal.

I am unable pass values back to base page.

my jquery is as below:-

```
$("#addForm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        scroll: true,
        overlay: {
            "background-color": "#000",
            "opacity": "0.5",
            "-moz-opacity": "0.5"
        }
    });

$("#btnAddSession").click(function(event) {
    var url = "Result.aspx?key=" + encodeURIComponent($("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").val());            
    $("#popup").attr("src", url);
    $("#addForm").dialog("open");
```

my div is as below:-

```
<div id="addForm" title="Dialog Title" >

<iframe id="popup"  width="480"></iframe>
</div>
```

This opens the new aspx in the jquery modal and passes the value of textbox which i access serverside to perform my search and bing to gridview. But unable to pass values back to base page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. (I've fixed the biggest things for you.)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the content of your iframe with something like this:

```
$("#yourID", top.document);
```

**OR**

```
$("#yourID", parent.document.body);
```

And welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Thanks TNC, but my values are at server side. I need to pass the values which are selected by user at runtime from the grid back to parent... am sure it must be a small workaround but confused, nonethless..

Comment: You could store the data as a session, and upon confirmation on your parent query the session.  Would that work?